# Convert array of comma separated strings to array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I want to convert an array to object with key-value pairs.

The array is like this:

`latLngArray = [ '52.12,-106.65', '53.53,-113.50' ]`

I want to convert it to array of objects like this:

`[{lat: 52.12, lng: -106.65}, 
 {lat: 53.53, lng: -113.50}]`

I tried to separate each element in the array with `split` but didn't help.

How can I convert this array to an object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this with simple `map()`

```js
latLngArray = ['52.12,-106.65', '53.53,-113.50'];
result = latLngArray.map(coords => {
  const [lat, lng] = coords.split(',');
  return {
    lat,
    lng
  };
});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I apply `parseFloat` to your solution to convert the numbers to float?

Comment: Consider doing `const [lat, lng] = coords.split(',').map(Number)`

Comment: return {lat: parseFloat(lat), lng: parseFloat(lng)};